# byte[] as DOS Date

Tags: c#, byte, dos

Can someone help me? I have a byte[2] with values:

```
byte[0] = 113
byte[1] = 66
```

How do I get a the date through the DOS date format from this 2 bytes?

Comment: Well what date is that meant to be? What *exactly* do you mean by "DOS date format"?

Comment: Where did those two bytes come from?

Comment: Maybe you are talking about a FAT date.  Bits 0-4 = day, bits 5-8 = month, bits 9-15 = year starting at 1980.

Comment: I got two bytes from a server and these two are supposed to give me either 2013/03/14 or 2013/03/17 date output.Do you know what DOS date format is? That is the info that I received.

Answer (score 6):

As @HansPassant said...

```
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 113, 66 };

var day = (bytes[0] >> 3);
var month = ((bytes[0] & 0x7) << 1) | (bytes[1] >> 7);
var year = (bytes[1] >> 1) + 1980;
```

would give you 2013/02/14